# Is there an applet like Haste but for images?

Tags: software-recommendation, applet, image-processing

For quick simple image hosting to post on forums and such?

Comment: Do you really need a desktop SW for that? Don’t the web services like Imgur, ImgBB, TinyPic etc. suffice?

Comment: Is this about Ubuntu anyway?

Comment: @ubashu There's an app for it in the default Ubuntu repositories. This is one of those times when 3 reviewers don't know about a specific app in the default Ubuntu repositories, therefore the reviewers vote as if this app doesn't exist and none of them checks back after reviewing which leaves me to clean up the mess.

Comment: @karel sorry... won't happen again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Shotwell digital photo organizer application and select an image to publish in the Shotwell library or add an image to the library and select it.
2. From the Shotwell menu select *File* -> *Publish* to publish the image or click the *Publish* button in the bottom toolbar.
3. Image hosting websites can be added to the Publishing list by selecting *Edit* -> *Preferences* -> *Plugins* tab -> check the checkbox to the left of the selected website as shown in the screenshot.

   [image]